# copy files beginning with a certain letter

Tags: csh

edit:

Thanks guys - so if I do "ls J*", why doesn't that list all the files beginning with J?

I just want to copy directories beginning with the letter J into another folder in my (cshell) terminal window? It must be one quick line surely, but I can't seem to get it to work, nor can I find the answer online.

Can someone put me out of my misery please?

Comment: well first I tried listing them with "ls ./J*" but that just gave me loads of other filenames. The I tried doing a loop: "foreach file ('ls -1 | hgrep J')     cp -r <destination folder>    end" but I got a message about "missing destination file operand after <destination folder"

Comment: yeah the directories and everything in them

Answer (score 2):

Shell globbing?

```
cp -r J* /path/to/other/dir
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cp -r J* /destination/path/
```

the -r option lets you copy directories recursively